# What are the counter examples books for Abstract algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, examples-counterexamples, book-recommendation

In mathematics field which book best for counter examples of group theory, linear algebra?

Comment: I can't say we have a preexisting post that covers this... so this one may well stand!  I'm personally not sure I've seen such a book for these particular fields.

Comment: What would that look like? Would it state every logical proposition about groups that isn't true and give a counter-example?

Comment: In "Gelbaum B.R., Olmsted, J.M.H.: Theorems and Counterexamples in Mathematics, Springer (1990)" the first chapter is about "group theory" and "linear algebra".

Comment: @JohnDouma There's precedent for such books, e.g.  Steen and Seebach's *Counterexamples in topology* and Hutchins' *Examples of commutative rings.* Usually they just contain context about what the terms mean, constructions, proofs about what the constructions do, but little or no exposition about the theory in general.

Comment: @Gerd Please consider formulating your comment as a solution.

Comment: @rschwieb I will do that if the question reopens.

Comment: @Gerd It's reopened.

Answer (score 10):

In the book

"Gelbaum B.R., Olmsted, J.M.H.: Theorems and Counterexamples in Mathematics, Springer (1990)"

the first chapter is about algebra with the subchapters "Group Theory", "Algebras" and "Linear Algebra". There is a list at the beginning of the book with all the examples covered.

Answer (score 2):

It does not cover linear algebra but, for group theory, the book [Examples of Groups](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0936428015) by Michael Weinstein is a gem.  It's an older book, but there appear to be used copies available online.